# VS code shortcut open terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, hotkeys

I try figure how when I open me terminal its automatically move to the right panel side.
General behaviour is from bottom and then I must manually set move bar to right side.

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking - the default keybinding to toggle the panel's view is CTRL + J.  If you move the panel to the right, it should continue to open and close one the right only.

Comment: https://postimg.cc/2V5f1QXY => this i need hide whole upper bar